# Use upper-case as word separator in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I can't find out how to use upper-case letters as word separators in Sublime Text 2.

What I want is the following behaviour: in some C++ IDE I like, using ctrl+left/right when cursor is in a word like thisIsAComposedWord will move cursor to next upper case in the word (or to the beginning/end of the word).

There's something in Sublime text called "word separators" that seems to do that, it appears his way in the default preferences file:

```
// Characters that are considered to separate words
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
```

So can I insert upper-case in that list? Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can move by "Subword" with the following Keybinds:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+left"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subwords", "forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["alt+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subword_ends", "forward": true} },
```

This recognizes camelCase and under_score.

You can also move by Word with

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+left"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "words", "forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "word_ends", "forward": true} }
```

This recognizes "word separators" as specified in your settings file.

Comment: Camel humps in sublime text. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Sublime Text in Linux (Ubuntu) and this works for me:

In your Settings-User add the same content of the "word-separators" by default (which is that you put in the question). Then, to the string add the regular expression of a Upper-Case letter [A-Z]. The result is:

```
{
   "word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?[A-Z]"
}
```

In order to move to the next upper case in a Word, I use Alt + Left/Right arrow.

Edit:

Regular expression doesn't work. The answer is not valid.

Comment: Note that on OS X it's Cmd + Left/Right arrow :)

Comment: Thanks! Strangely enough, it doesn't work with `[A-Z]`, but does with unelegant `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`... And it doesn't have the good behavior, whereas `alt+left/right` has it. So replacing `alt+left/right` by `ctrl+left/right` works for what I asked. Though, I'd also like to be able to delete subwords, and I couldn't figure out how to do it, the `"by": "subwords"` options doesn't seem to be available for `"command": "delete_word"`.

Comment: If you are a VIM user or you have enabled the Vintage Mode, you can delete the word with 'cw' (change word)

Comment: Just as a note, [A-Z] doesn't work because it's not a regex (as you figured out). Note the only escaped characters are backslash and double quote. There would be a bunch more if it were a regex.

Comment: word_separators is list of characters, not regex. It doesn't even look like regex.